# How to create a mask of substrings using np.where or list comprehensions?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have two python lists of strings that I would like to compare. The first is my main list, containing a series of long codes. The second is a list of partial strings.

```
input:
list1 = ['fda3232', 'fcg3224', 'kgj5543', '3323fda9832', 'ffz3392', '221gks9483', 'mnx8385', 'aaz9323', '332kgj4323'] 

list2 = ['fda', 'kgj', 'mxx', 'mnx']
```

The desired result is a mask of list 1, populated by the substrings from list two. If no match is found, list3 can return 0, np.nan, '-', or similar. In other words, I'm looking for the following:

```
output: 

list3 = ['fda', np.nan, 'kgj', 'fda', np.nan, np.nan, 'mnx', np.nan, 'kgj']
```

With help from folks in another thread, I was able to get close. However, these results return the values in list1, but I would like my result to return the matching substring from list2.

```
solution 1: 
list3 = [x if any(y in x for y in list2) else np.nan for x in list1]

solution 2:
list3 = np.where([np.sum(np.char.find(x, sub=list2)+1) for x in list1], list1, np.NaN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = ['fda3232', 'fcg3224', 'kgj5543', '3323fda9832', 'ffz3392', '221gks9483', 'mnx8385', 'aaz9323', '332kgj4323']

list2 = ['fda', 'kgj', 'mxx', 'mnx']

def isin(haystack):
    for needle in list2:
        if needle in haystack:
            return needle
    return np.nan

list3 = [isin(haystack) for haystack in list1]
print(list3)
```

Which yields

```
['fda', nan, 'kgj', 'fda', nan, nan, 'mnx', nan, 'kgj']
```

Your could even put it in a comprehension:

```
list3 = [result[0]
         for haystack in list1
         for result in [[needle for needle in list2 if needle in haystack] or [np.nan]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

That function will return the compared list. It checks whether `substring` is in the `main string` if that is `True` the `x` list is appended. After the one substring is done, the `if statement` checks whether there was a match. If was it appends it, if not it appends a `None` value

```
list1 = ['fda3232', 'fcg3224', 'kgj5543', '3323fda9832', 'ffz3392', '221gks9483', 'mnx8385', 'aaz9323', '332kgj4323'] 
list2 = ['fda', 'kgj', 'mxx', 'mnx']

def chan(list1, list2):
    for i in list1:
        x = []
        for j in list2:
            if j in i:
                x.append(j)
        if len(x) > 0:
            lister.append(''.join(x))
        else:
            lister.append(None)
    return lister
print(chan(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Logic is, to suppress all digits in `list1` to get a code, and see if that code is in `list2`. If yes, append the code, else any other placeholder like `-` or `nan`.

```
list3 = []
for item in list1:
    code = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', item)
    if code in list2:
        list3.append(code)
    else:
        list3.append(np.nan)

print(list3)
```

Output:

```
['fda', nan, 'kgj', 'fda', nan, nan, 'mnx', nan, 'kgj']
```